# Прозрачный интерфейс всплывающего меню в blender

Tags: blender

Скачал blender 3d 2.91.2 и никак не могу решить проблему с интерфейсом. Инструменты и слова в меню как полу-прозрачные, а у выпадающих окон нет фона. Так же у объекта не видны ни грани ни ребра ни вершины. При его резании или вытягивании он как буд-то остается монолитным. Помогите чем можете. Заранее спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Тут может быть 2 проблемы.

#### 1) Ваша видеокарта не поддерживает OpenGL 3.3.

Начиная с версии 2.80 минимальная версия OpenGL которую должна поддерживать видеокарта - 3.1,  2.81 - 3.3

Т.е. либо вы используете старую версию, либо вам нужна новая видеокарта с поддержкой OpenGL 3.3

#### 2) У вас видеокарта AMD. AMD обновила драйвера для видеокарты 20.11.2, где они поломали поддержку OpenGL.

Что можно сделать во втором случае?

1. Откатить драйвера до предыдущей версии (20.11.1).
2. Некоторые ошибки исправляются, вы можете попробовать свежий билд 2.92 (https://builder.blender.org), однако работоспособность не гарантируется.